# Make Finder treat TextMate .tmbundle as regular directory

Tags: finder, textmate

Is there a (reversible) way to make Finder treat TextMate **.tmbundle** packages as regular folders? Right now, to view a bundle's contents, I need to right-click and select *Show Package Contents* to view or edit any of the file/folders it contains, which is kind of a pain. Also, opening a file contained in a bundle directly from a program is impossible, as the *Open...* dialog doesn't have the *Show Package Contents* option that Finder does.

As an extra, is there a way to (reversibly) do this for other packages, such as **.pkg** and **.app**? I imagine the process would be identical, but you never know...

Thanks!

Comment: I think **.tmbundle** is registered by TextMate to be treated as such. So you'll need to edit a file within TextMate.app to make the system treat it as a regular directory that you can navigate to. The best way to do this is to open the directory from terminal `open foo.tmbundle/Content/`. It would help if you mention how are you editing the files and using what application to edit them.

Comment: @ismail - currently I'm editing the enclosed .tmlanguage files in Sublime Text 2, but that's not really the issue. What I would like to know is how to change the behavior of "special" folders like .tmbundle, .pkg, and .app to either act like a regular folder, or behave in their current special manner.

Comment: like i said certain extensions are hardwired within related apps. **.tmbundle* within TextMate, **.pkg** most probably within finder along with **.app**. How about turning on "hidden items" in sublime, does that treat the folders as ordinary folders? That's the only way I can think of at the moment.